# Multipath device name doesn't display correctly

Tags: linux, vmware, block-device, iscsi

I'm playing with iscsi and I'm trying to figure out why the vendor/product names aren't showing up correctly. I've restarted all the appropriate services along with a reboot.

Listed below are the output along with an excerpt of the config file.

Output:

```
LUN-48 (1IET_00020001) dm-0 IET,VIRTUAL-DISK
size=480M features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
| `- 3:0:0:1 sdb 8:16 failed faulty running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active
`- 7:0:0:1 sdd 8:48 active ready  running
LUN-30 (1IET_00010001) dm-1 IET,VIRTUAL-DISK
size=300M features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=active
| `- 8:0:0:1 sdc 8:32 active ready  running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
`- 5:0:0:1 sde 8:64 failed faulty running
```

Here's an excerpt from `multipath.conf`

```
devices {
    device {
            vendor "VMware"
            product "Virtual Disk"
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to see where and why?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you expect your `multipath.conf` file to accomplish, but what you've shown above is effectively a no-op as far as I can tell.  The `device` section matches devices based on the `vendor`, `product`, and `revision` keywords, and then applies specific overrides.  You have some match criteria there, but you're not actually providing configuration information.

Take a look at [this document](http://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/DM_Multipath/config_file_devices.html), which shows an example `devices` section that overrides some global configuration options.

Other than that, the vendor and product names look just fine.  `IET` is the vendor reported by the iSCSI Enterprise Target driver, so I assume that's where you're getting your LUNs.

Comment: Yea, I was talking to a coworker who told me you could apply whatever name you want to the "Device," but apparently that isn't the case. I spent an hour or so trying to get the name to display correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I can not leave comments, so I'll post this as an answer.

There is possibility that virtualization causes strange vendor/product names, which are not recognized properly by the toolchain. I have had issues with serial numbers on VirtualBox that did not reproduce in non-virtualized environment.

Comment: visualization or virtualization?

Comment: Virtualization, it was a misprint